# What can I do of this on bind custom view event? Please tell

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a chat app. This is the Chat Activity Here I have a list view for displaying chat.But on its bind custom view I am getting the following errors please tell me how to resolve these errors.
All the used variables are predefined. I have got these errors after entering the repeat code at the last. Please tell me how to resolve these errors

Error on bind custom view for a list view

```
if (_data.get((int)_position).get("from").toString().equals(data.getString("mobile", "")) && _data.get((int)_position).get("to").toString().equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"))) {
    whole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    own_full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    other_full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    _decryptString(_data.get((int)_position).get("mes").toString(), data.getString("mobile", ""));
    mes_own.setText(decrypted);
    time_own.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("time").toString());
    if (_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString().equals("")) {
        image_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        image_own.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString())).into(image_own);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString())).placeholder(R.drawable.ertyu).into(image_own);
        image_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                intt.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ViewimageActivity.class);
                intt.putExtra("url", _data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString());
                startActivity(intt);
            }
        });
        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("mes").toString().equals("")) {
            mes_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    if (_data.get((int)_position).get("video").toString().equals("")) {
        video_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        video_own.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                intt.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ViewvideoActivity.class);
                intt.putExtra("url", _data.get((int)_position).get("video").toString());
                startActivity(intt);
            }
        });
        mes_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    _Round(18, 0, 18, 18, "#FFFFFF", linear5);
    if (_data.get((int)_position).get("file").toString().equals("")) {
        file_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mes_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        file_own.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
else {
    if (_data.get((int)_position).get("to").toString().equals(data.getString("mobile", "")) && _data.get((int)_position).get("from").toString().equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"))) {
        _Round(0, 18, 18, 18, "#FFFFFF", linear6);
        whole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        own_full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        other_full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _decryptString(_data.get((int)_position).get("mes").toString(), _data.get((int)_position).get("from").toString());
        mes_other.setText(decrypted);
        textview4.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("time").toString());
        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString().equals("")) {
            image_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            image_other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString())).into(image_other);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString())).placeholder(R.drawable.ertyu).into(image_other);
            image_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View _view) {
                    intt.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ViewimageActivity.class);
                    intt.putExtra("url", _data.get((int)_position).get("image").toString());
                    startActivity(intt);
                }
            });
            if (_data.get((int)_position).get("mes").toString().equals("")) {
                mes_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("video").toString().equals("")) {
            video_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            mes_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            video_other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View _view) {
                    intt.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ViewvideoActivity.class);
                    intt.putExtra("url", _data.get((int)_position).get("video").toString());
                    startActivity(intt);
                }
            });
        }
        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("file").toString().equals("")) {
            file_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            mes_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            file_other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    else {
        whole.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    _detectLinks(mes_own);
    _detectLinks(mes_other);
}
whole.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View _view) {
        fokat = 0;
        for(int _repeat199 = 0; _repeat199 < (int)(delete.size()); _repeat199++) {
            if (delete.get((int)(fokat)).doubleValue() == _position) {
                whole.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                delete.remove((int)(fokat));
                if (delete.size() == 0) {
                    _name();
                }
            }
            else {
                whole.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFCE4EC);
                delete.add(Double.valueOf(_position));
                _delete_tray_visible();
            }
            fokat++;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

And I am getting the following 76 errors

9. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
   imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
   ^
   Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

10. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

---

11. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

---

12. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

---

13. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete BlockStatements

---

14. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete SwitchBlock

---

15. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 839)
    imageserver.child(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))).addOnFailureListener(_imageserver_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_imageserver_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task>() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

---

16. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 841)
    public Task then(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    The method then(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>) of type ChatActivity must override or implement a supertype method

---

17. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 843)
    }}).addOnCompleteListener(_imageserver_upload_success_listener);
    ^^^^
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

---

18. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 844)
    }
    else {
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

---

19. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 850)
    case REQ_CD_VIDEO:
    ^^^^
    Syntax error on token "case", delete this token

---

20. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 854)
    if (_data.getClipData() != null) {
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

21. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 855)
    for (int _index = 0; _index < _data.getClipData().getItemCount(); _index++) {
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

22. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 856)
    ClipData.Item _item = _data.getClipData().getItemAt(_index);
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

23. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 861)
    _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _data.getData()));
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

24. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 863)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", { expected after this token

---

25. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 869)
    }}).addOnCompleteListener(_videoserver_upload_success_listener);
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

---

26. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 871)
    else {
    ^^^^
    Syntax error on token "else", { expected

---

27. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 876)
    case REQ_CD_ALL:
    ^^^^
    Syntax error on token "case", delete this token

---

28. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 879)
    if (_data != null) {
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved to a variable

---

29. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 880)
    if (_data.getClipData() != null) {
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

30. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 881)
    for (int _index = 0; _index < _data.getClipData().getItemCount(); _index++) {
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

31. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 882)
    ClipData.Item _item = _data.getClipData().getItemAt(_index);
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

32. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 887)
    _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _data.getData()));
    ^^^^^
    _data cannot be resolved

---

33. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 902)
    default:
    ^^^^^^^
    Syntax error on token "default", invalid Label

---

34. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 904)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

35. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1064)
    im_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

36. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1064)
    im_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

---

37. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1064)
    im_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

---

38. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1064)
    im_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

39. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1064)
    im_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

---

40. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1066)
    public void onClick(View _view) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Duplicate method onClick(View) in type ChatActivity

---

41. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1066)
    public void onClick(View _view) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    The method onClick(View) of type ChatActivity must override or implement a supertype method

---

42. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1079)
    });
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

43. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1079)
    });
    ^
    Syntax error on token ")", { expected

---

44. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1081)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

45. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1159)
    public void _name tray visible () {
    ^^^^^
    void is an invalid type for the variable _name

---

46. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1159)
    public void _name tray visible () {
    ^^^^
    tray cannot be resolved to a type

---

47. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1162)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

48. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1169)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", ; expected

---

49. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

50. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

---

51. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

---

52. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

53. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

---

54. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement

---

55. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1248)
    video_own.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

---

56. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1250)
    public void onClick(View _view) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    The method onClick(View) of type ChatActivity.Listview1Adapter must override or implement a supertype method

---

57. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1252)
    intt.putExtra("url", _data.get((int)_position).get("video").toString());
    ^^^^^^^^^
    _position cannot be resolved to a variable

---

58. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1255)
    });
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", invalid ConstructorHeaderName

---

59. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1256)
    mes_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Syntax error on token "setVisibility", Identifier expected after this token

---

60. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1256)
    mes_own.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ^^^^
    Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList

---

61. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1257)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", { expected

---

62. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1267)
    else {
    ^^^^
    Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

---

63. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

64. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

---

65. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

---

66. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

67. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

---

68. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete BlockStatements

---

69. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

70. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

---

71. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

72. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1301)
    video_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

---

73. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1303)
    public void onClick(View _view) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Duplicate method onClick(View) in type ChatActivity

---

74. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1307)
    }
    });
    }
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

---

75. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1317)
    }
    else {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

---

76. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1323)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

77. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1349)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

---

78. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

---

79. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

---

80. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

81. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

---

82. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete BlockStatements

---

83. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

---

84. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/640/app/src/main/java/raxdevs/chatapp/ChatActivity.java (at line 1402)
    }
    ^
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

---

84 problems (76 errors, 8 warnings)**

Comment: *I have got these errors after entering the repeat code at the last. Please tell me how to resolve these errors* - what errors?

Comment: Given in the code

Comment: Please read the code

Comment: Have a look at `ChatActivity.java (at line 839) `  - this is the reason that you don't do heaps of coding without checking if it compiles.  Do a bit, then check check often.

Comment: These are the lines from 839 to 942

Comment: Check.    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rax89chat.appspot.com/o/ChatActivity.java?alt=media&token=400ee7fe-02dc-4718-a43e-ef0d6f726063